# Submitting hidden input values with jquery $.post empty db columns and Notice: Undefined index

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I can see the values passed in the console but get nothing in the db and output is undefined errors. I d'ont think that the error is in my JS, I think the error is in how the PHP file grabs the data from .post

Here is my code:

Form:

```
<form id="data_form" action="" method="post">
    <input id="csActvSkuIp" name="csActvSkuIp" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input id="csActvSkuDtlsIp" name="csActvSkuDtlsIp" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csActvSkuCasePickIp" name="csActvSkuCasePickIp" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csActvSkuCasePickDtlsIp" name="csActvSkuCasePickDtlsIp" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csInputPicksPerMonthIp" name="csInputPicksPerMonthIp" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csInputPickRateIp" name="csInputPickRateIp" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csInputPickWrkr1Ip" name="csInputPickWrkr1Ip" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csInputPickWrkr2Ip" name="csInputPickWrkr2Ip" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csInputPickWrkr3Ip" name="csInputPickWrkr3Ip" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csInputPrcntPckingIp" name="csInputPrcntPckingIp" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csInputPickCostIp" name="csInputPickCostIp" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csCurrentPcpmIp" name="csCurrentPcpmIp" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csSubscriptionPerMonthIp" name="csSubscriptionPerMonthIp" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csPrcPerPickIp" name="csPrcPerPickIp" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csCartOnlySaveIp" name="csCartOnlySaveIp" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csSubPerMnLightsIp" name="csSubPerMnLightsIp" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csPrcPerPickLightsIp" name="csPrcPerPickLightsIp" type="hidden" value=""  />
    <input id="csCartOnlySaveLightsIp" name="csCartOnlySaveLightsIp" type="hidden" value=""  />

    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // process the form
        $('#data_form').submit(function(event) {
            alert('form submited');

            // get the form data
            var formData = {
                csActvSkuIp                 : $( "input[name=csActvSkuIp]" ).val(),
                csActvSkuDtlsIp             : $( "input[name=csActvSkuDtlsIp]" ).val(),
                csActvSkuCasePickIp         : $( "input[name=csActvSkuCasePickIp]" ).val(),
                csActvSkuCasePickDtlsIp     : $( "input[name=csActvSkuCasePickDtlsIp]" ).val(),
                csInputPicksPerMonthIp      : $( "input[name=csInputPicksPerMonthIp]" ).val(),
                csInputPickRateIp           : $( "input[name=csInputPickRateIp]" ).val(),
                csInputPickWrkr1Ip          : $( "input[name=csInputPickWrkr1Ip]" ).val(),
                csInputPickWrkr2Ip          : $( "input[name=csInputPickWrkr2Ip]" ).val(),
                csInputPickWrkr3Ip          : $( "input[name=csInputPickWrkr3Ip]" ).val(),
                csInputPrcntPckingIp        : $( "input[name=csInputPrcntPckingIp]" ).val(),
                csInputPickCostIp           : $( "input[name=csInputPickCostIp]" ).val(),
                csCurrentPcpmIp             : $( "input[name=csCurrentPcpmIp]" ).val(),
                csSubscriptionPerMonthIp    : $( "input[name=csSubscriptionPerMonthIp]" ).val(),
                csPrcPerPickIp              : $( "input[name=csPrcPerPickIp]" ).val(),
                csCartOnlySaveIp            : $( "input[name=csCartOnlySaveIp]" ).val(),
                csSubPerMnLightsIp          : $( "input[name=csSubPerMnLightsIp]" ).val(),
                csPrcPerPickLightsIp        : $( "input[name=csPrcPerPickLightsIp]" ).val(),
                csCartOnlySaveLightsIp      : $( "input[name=csCartOnlySaveLightsIp]" ).val(),
            };
            //alert(formData.activesku);

            console.log( formData );


            // process the form
            $.post('<?php echo $csamurl ; ?>', function(formData) {

                // place success code here
                $("#feedback").html(formData);
                alert(csActvSkuIp)

            })
                .fail(function(data) {
                    alert('this didnt work')
                });

            // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>


<div id="feedback"></div>
```

PHP:

```
$ascasedtlsd        = $_POST["csActvSkuCasePickDtlsIp"];
$activeskud         = $_POST["csActvSkuIp"];
$askudttlsd         = $_POST["csActvSkuDtlsIp"];
$ascasepickd        = $_POST["csActvSkuCasePickIp"];
$pickspermonthd     = $_POST["csInputPicksPerMonthIp"];
$pickrated          = $_POST["csInputPickRateIp"];
$pickwrkroned       = $_POST["csInputPickWrkr1Ip"];
$pickwrkrtwod       = $_POST["csInputPickWrkr2Ip"];
$pickwrkrthrd       = $_POST["csInputPickWrkr3Ip"];
$prcntpickd         = $_POST["csInputPrcntPckingIp"];
$pickcostd          = $_POST["csInputPickCostIp"];
$currentpcpmd       = $_POST["csCurrentPcpmIp"];
$subpmad            = $_POST["csSubscriptionPerMonthIp"];
$pprmnthad          = $_POST["csPrcPerPickIp"];
$cartonlyd          = $_POST["csCartOnlySaveIp"];
$subpmbd            = $_POST["csSubPerMnLightsIp"];
$ppmnthbd           = $_POST["csPrcPerPickLightsIp"];
$cartlightd         = $_POST["csCartOnlySaveLightsIp"];


global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'codeshelf';

$wpdb->insert(
$table_name,
array(
'time' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
'activesku'         => $activeskud,
'askudttls'         => $askudttlsd,
'ascasepick'        => $ascasepickd,
'ascasedtls'        => $ascasedtlsd,
'pickspermonth'     => $pickspermonthd,
'pickrate'          => $pickrated,
'pickwrkrone'       => $pickwrkroned,
'pickwrkrtwo'       => $pickwrkrtwod,
'pickwrkrthr'       => $pickwrkrthrd,
'prcntpick'         => $prcntpickd,
'pickcost'          => $pickcostd,
'currentpcpm'       => $currentpcpmd,
'subpma'            => $subpmad,
'pprmntha'          => $pprmnthad,
'cartonly'          => $cartonlyd,
'subpmb'            => $subpmbd,
'ppmnthb'           => $ppmnthbd,
'cartlight'         => $cartlightd,
)
);
```

This is a WordPress plugin I am working on, but I have tested the post using

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

The values of the form are being set with a click function and this works also, the only thing that I am not having any luck with is this.

Comment: You need to enclose form value with single quote input[name='value'] or refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the form itselt.
try it.

```
$.post( "test.php", $( "#testform" ).serialize() );
```

Comment: You were right it was much easier and the lines of code much smaller. In the end this helped a ton! My real issue was calling $wpdb on the next page, figured it out by doing var_dump() and when it returned null I knew there was an issue. Right now I am using include wp-load.php to initialize the wpdb object on the page I am passing the data to, bad form though so I am going to dig into the hooks for wp more. Thanks a bunch for all of your help, both of you!

Answer (score 0):

But your `var formData` does not include the submit:

```
submit: $( "input[name=submit]" ).val(),
```

But as said @jay using `.serialize()` would be much more easier.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I would mark you guys both but new here.